# syntax error using sqlite

Tags: android

I am really sorry to ask this silly question. I have been onto this error for last 1 hour and could not find the problem from my eyes. If someone can help me find the problem I would really appreciate. I know this is not a error handling blog but I don't have a choice. Following is my DB code:

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "RCdata";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "events";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TAG = "RCDataBaseAdapter";
private static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_EVENT = "eventsname";
private static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION ="description";

// Database creation sql statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_EVENTS =
        "create table events (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "eventsname text not null, " 
        + "description text not null);";


private Context context;
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
      public RCDatabaseAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    //super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context); 
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }   

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_EVENTS);
    //db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_Priests);


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
            + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Events");
      onCreate(db);

}
}
//---opens the database---
public RCDatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---closes the database---    
public void close() 
{
    DBHelper.close();
}

public long insertEvent(String eventname, String description)
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_EVENT, eventname);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);

    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

}


//---deletes a particular event---
public boolean deleteEvent(long rowId) 
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_CREATE_EVENTS, KEY_ROWID + 
            "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}


public Cursor getAllTitles() 
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_CREATE_EVENTS, new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID, 
            KEY_EVENT,
            KEY_DESCRIPTION}, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null);
}

//---retrieves a particular title---
public Cursor getEvent(long rowId) throws SQLException 
{

    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_CREATE_EVENTS, new String[] {
                    KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_EVENT, 
                    KEY_DESCRIPTION                     
                    }, 
                    KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                    null,
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;                  


}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
near “create”: syntax error: ,
while compiling: SELECT _id,
eventsname, description
FROM create table events (_id
integer primary key
autoincrement, eventsname
text not null, description text
not null);
```

Comment: Could you add the code where you are using `DATABASE_CREATE_Events`? Seems like you're trying to `select` data from the table while passing a `create` query.

Comment: I have edited the code above. Thanks for your initiate

Comment: DATABASE_CREATE_EVENTS I had changed the name to all caps wondering that might be the issue but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your methods of `getAllTitles`, `deleteEvent`, `getEvent` all use the `create` syntax in a query to get records. You need to pass the appropriate syntax to the `query` method. Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)
An example, your `getEvent` method might work like this.

```
db.query(true, "events", new String[] {
                    KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_EVENT, 
                    KEY_DESCRIPTION                     
                    }, 
                    KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                    null,
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I took this code from the http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1763?supportItem=4 I am new to android and trying to connect to database for the first time. I wonder why that difference, I am sure it would have been hard for me to figure it out. It worked. Is there any website for database where I could learn with examples? For example if I have multiple tables for the database do I need to create all the get,insert,update methods for each tables??